# How can I set this picture to be displayed above?

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

http://test.dac-proiect.ro/landing-page/index.html

I want my image (blue circle) to start up as in the picture below

http://i57.tinypic.com/osxyll.jpg

This is code HTML:

```
            <div class="content">

            <div class="container-video">
                 <div class="text-sus">
                            <p>Set us perspiciatis</p>
                            <p>unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore <p>
                 </div>

                            <div class="video">

                            <img src="images/VIDEO.png" style="width:100%;height:auto;">


                            </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="imagine1"><img src="images/CERC-ALBASTRU.png" style="width:100%;height:auto;float:left;"></div>


            </div>
```

This is code CSS:

```
    .text-sus
{
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
}

.text-sus p:first-child
{
text-align:center;
margin:0;
}

.video{
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
}

.content
{
/*background:url(images/CERC-ALBASTRU.png);*/
width:100%;
height:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.container-video{
width:100%;
height:auto;
background:url(images/BODY-VERDE.png);
margin:0 auto;
overflow:auto;
}
```

I hope I managed to explain my problem iara redraw something I will come back with further details.

I tried to do that:

```
.imagine1 img{position:absolute;top:257px;z-index:-1}
```

Works easily code for my resolution but on other resolutions only is ok

Comment: Use a background image instead of an `<img />` tag (where you make the background green use an image)

Comment: Please format your code properly. Part of a good question is **impeccable** code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should indent a little your code to see better your skeleton. Try this:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-header">
            <div id="c1">
                <img src="images/APARAT-BANNER.png" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
            </div>
            <div id="c2">
                <p>Come on our both</p>
            </div>
            <div id="c3">   
                <img src="https://cloud04.nsh.ro:2083/cpsess6991769065/viewer/home%2fdacproie%2fpublic_html%2ftest%2flanding-page%2fimages/pachete.png" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imagine1">
        <img src="images/CERC-ALBASTRU.png" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-video">
            <div class="text-sus">
                <p>Set us perspiciatis</p>
                <p>unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore </p><p>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="video">         
                <img src="images/VIDEO.png" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the way to put it, without adding more CSS; thought. If it is not you are looking for, sorry D:

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the text and the video in an absolute div.

```css
body
{
margin:0;
}

.container{
width:100%;
/*height:100%;*/
background:white;
}

.container-header{
width:70%;
height:auto;

margin:0 auto;
overflow:auto;
}

.container-video{
width:100%;
height:auto;
background:url(http://test.dac-proiect.ro/landing-page/images/BODY-VERDE.png);
margin:0 auto;
overflow:auto;
}

#c1{height:auto;float:left; }
#c2{height:auto;float:left;background:antiquewhite }
#c3{height:auto;float:left; }



.text-sus
{
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
}

.text-sus p:first-child
{
text-align:center;
margin:0;
}

.video{
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
}

.content
{
/*background:url(images/CERC-ALBASTRU.png);*/
width:100%;
height:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}


#c1, #c2, #c3 {
    width: 33%; // 1/3 of 100%
 
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
            <div class="container-header">
                <div id="c1"><img src="http://test.dac-proiect.ro/landing-page/images/APARAT-BANNER.png" style="width:100%;height:auto;"></div>
                <div id="c2">
                    <p>Come on our both</p>
                </div>
                <div id="c3">
                    <img src="http://test.dac-proiect.ro/landing-page/images/pachete.png" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-video" style="position:relative;">
                <div style="position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:100%;">
                    <div class="text-sus">
                        <p>Set us perspiciatis</p>
                        <p>unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore </p><p>
                        </p></div>

                    <div class="video">
                        <img src="http://test.dac-proiect.ro/landing-page/images/VIDEO.png" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="imagine1"><img src="http://test.dac-proiect.ro/landing-page/images/CERC-ALBASTRU.png" style="width:100%;height:auto;float:left;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```